# How do I get rid of the following error in DDA line Algorithm in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, gcc-warning, bgi, dda

File **line_3.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <dos.h>
#include <graphics.h>

void lineDDA(int, int, int, int);
void main() {
    int x1, y1, xn, yn;
    int gd = DETECT, gm;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, "");
    printf("Enter the starting coordinates of line: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &x1, &y1);
    printf("Enter the ending coordinates of line: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &xn, &yn);
    lineDDA(x1, y1, xn, yn);
    getch();
}

void lineDDA(int x1, int y1, int xn, int yn) {
    int dx, dy, m, i;
    m = (yn - y1) / (xn - x1);
    for (i = x1; i <= xn; i++) {
        if (m <= 1) {
            dx = 1;
            dy = m * dx;
        } else {
            dy = 1;
            dx = dy / m;
        }
        x1 = x1 + dx;
        y1 = y1 + dy;
        putpixel(x1, y1, RED);
        delay(20);
    }
    //  MISSING CODE
```

Compilation Command:

```
gcc line_3.c -o line_3 -lm
```

Error:

```
meshramsd@ubuntu:~$ gcc line_3.c -o line_3 -lm
/tmp/ccYuGyd4.o: In function `main':
line_3.c:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `initgraph'
line_3.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `grprintf'
line_3.c:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `grscanf'
line_3.c:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `grprintf'
line_3.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to `grscanf'
line_3.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `grgetch'
/tmp/ccYuGyd4.o: In function `lineDDA':
line_3.c:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `putpixel'
line_3.c:(.text+0x11d): undefined reference to `delay'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help

Comment: Because it needs the Borland TurboC libraries and compiler?

Comment: The console graphics library on Linux is [`ncurses`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).
You will need to install the `ncurses` development package `libncurses5-dev`
in Ubuntu to compile against its API and link the library. Then you
will need to [learn how to use it](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).
Your Borland TurboC source code will require extensive modification.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have much to do, just compile it as 'gcc line_3.c -o line_3 -lgraph', surely you will get your answer.
All these function showing error are of lgraph package. :)

Comment: this solution workked but can you please explain why to remove lgraph?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete, it would not compile as posted.

The code uses a DOS library, probably from Borland, to access the DOS graphics display cards.  This is very old and does not translate well to the linux environment.

Either provide your own implementation of all the graphics functions (unlikely), or use a linux specific graphics API.

Comment: And what do you think is the best way to learn Linux specific graphics APIs. Thanks.